# Настройка Debian LAMP

Tags: apache, debian, linux

Здравствуйте.

Заказал VPS с Debian, теперь появилось куча проблем с его настройкой. Поиск информации в сети привёл только к ещё большему количеству проблем. У меня имеется несколько вопросов по настройке.

1. Стоит Apache2, каким образом к нему прикрутить домен иили домен второго уровня, чтоб он выдавал определённую папку?
2. Как установить FTP-сервер, чтоб для каждого пользователя была своя папка? Установил что-то как-то с трудом, при подключении пишет:

   > `Ответ:     500 OOPS: vsftpd: not found: directory given in 'secure_chroot_dir':/var/run/vsftpd`
   > `Ошибка:     Критическая ошибка`
   > `Ошибка:     Невозможно подключиться к серверу`
3. Apache не видит .htaccess в папке var/www . Тоже перепробовал кучу способов, ничего не помогает.
4. Отказывается работать sendmail(). Вроде установил этот какой-то ext4 вроде. В конце установки он написал FAILED.

Comment: лучше всего разделить вопросы на отдельные топики, по апачу, фтп и сендмейлу отдельно. И выложить конфиги.

Answer (score 1):

3) в настройку виртуалХоста добавьте:

```
<Directory />
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

и убедитесь что модуль mod_rewrite загружен

Comment: shurik, Всё сделал, мод rewrite включён. Перезапускал апач несколько раз. Всё-равно не видит .htaccess

Comment: Скиньте конфиг своего виртуал хоста

Comment: ну блин, я же написал, AllowOverride All

а у вас AllowOverride None

Comment: В каком месте там ставить AllowOverride All?
Везде заменить? Или где?
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

вот здесь заменил, всё равно не помогло..

Comment: везде заменяйте, не ошибетесь :)

А также не забываем про перезагрузку апача